# Unity: Are you missing an assembly reference?

Tags: unity-game-engine

There's this unity tutorial called space shooter and for some reason i am getting the following error:

```
AppData/Local/Unity/cache/packages/packages.unity.com/com.unity.package-manager-ui@2.0.3/Editor/Sources/Services/Upm/UpmBaseOperation.cs(34,43): 
error CS1061: Type 'UnityEditor.PackageManager.PackageInfo' does not contain a definition for 'author' and no extension method 'author' of type 'UnityEditor.PackageManager.PackageInfo' could be found.
Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

Its just the beginning of the project and i haven't even written any scripts. I have no idea what this means.

Comment: Any luck with this? I am getting the same error.

Comment: Yes. Apparently Unity had some files missing or had some kind of bug. Updating Unity did the trick for me.

Answer (score 4):

I just encountered this myself, and it comes from erroneous settings in "manifest.json" file, found inside /Packages/

Delete (or move) the manifest file, even while Unity is running, and Unity will rebuild it. The errors then go away.